# Do the experimentally obtained XPS Binding energies come from different shells? or all from the same shell ($1s$ $K$-shell)?

Tags: photoelectric-effect, binding-energy, x-rays, ionization-energy

In experimentally obtained XPS atomic Binding Energy data like on NIST; is the ionization energy always for $1s$ electron, or it differs among elements? I checked the experimental data, and other theoretical data. The experimental energy value may correspond to theoretical data with lower energy than $1s$, but not always $1s$? Why would not experiment be able to excite electrons from $1s$ ($K$ shell) in this case?
What would be a reliable data source for XPS experimentally obtained binding energies?

Comment: Very unclear question. The tables would mention what levels the XPS binding energy is for. Give a link so that we do not need to speculate.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In this chart https://www.xpsdata.com/NIST_CHART.htm, e.g. for Fe it is 707.28 eV; whereas when I check other tables it is not the value for K-shell but  for  L3 shell. Other elements may also have different values from K-shell. My question is, why not all elements are K-shell value? is it experimental limitations and why? does it relate to the effective charge?  why do some elements do not have binding energy values here, and some other sources have? Is this experimental, and others are theoretical?

Answer (score 1):

The table that you referred to is for use with an XPS apparatus where the X-ray tube has an aluminium or magnesium anode (photon energies Al K$_\alpha$ at 1486 eV or Mg K$_\alpha$ at 1253 eV).

For a more complete table of binding energies, there are [pages compiled by Gwyn Williams](https://xdb.lbl.gov/Section1/Sec_1-1.html) in the X-ray Data Booklet at LBL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a self learner, so I face several problems. Why would using an excitation beam with Al K-alpha, or Mg K-alpha, make different values?